# how to refer xsd file in registry in wsdl

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I wish to r=read a xsd file available in registry in my WSDL (this is also in registry)

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/SearchMember/">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.memsrch.com/req"
            schemaLocation="**./MemberSearchReq.xsd**" />
        <xsd:import namespace="http://www.memsrch.com/resp"
            schemaLocation="**./MemberSearchRep.xsd**" />
    </xsd:schema>
```

This is erroring as shown below

> Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing './MemberSearchRep.xsd'.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\wso2esb-4.0.3\wso2esb-4.0.3\MemberSearchRep.xsd (The system cannot find the file specified)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2166)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:845)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:669)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(WSDLReaderImpl.java:630)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(WSDLReaderImpl.java:342)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2320)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2284)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2337)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2358)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2390)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.readInTheWSDLFile(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:2318)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.setup(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:922)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:309)
>       ... 22 more
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\wso2esb-4.0.3\wso2esb-4.0.3\MemberSearchRep.xsd (The system cannot find the file specified)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:79)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2156)
>       ... 34 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you solved this, if not please refer to this blog post how to setup wsdl's in the registry that import XSD's: http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.nl/2012/07/wso2-esb-proxy-from-registry.html.

Regards, nidkil

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "./" and make sure the XSD is in the same resource collection in the registry as the WSDL. The name of the resource should be the same as the name used in schemaLocation.

One note of caution, ensure you do not nest XSD's as this is currently not supported by the registry.

Regard, nidkil

Comment: Tried that and it also failed.

Comment: Can some one please help us on this ?